# Netty throttling Accept on boss thread

Tags: netty

During DoS attack it is observed that boss thread has accepted lot more connections than the server can process (especially the ssl handshake completion on accepted sockets was lagging far behind). We would like to throttle and not accept more connections when certain threshold are breached. In NIO we could disable temporarily via ~OP_ACCEPT flag. Is there any thing in Netty that would allow us do the same? What would be a recommended way to pause the boss thread from accepting more connections. Would it be a good solution to put a sleep in the boss thread or is there a better way out?

-Harshad.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the only way to achieve such a behavior is perform a blocking operation in your server handler.  You can specify a server handler by calling `ServerBootstrap.setParentHandler(...)'.  However, you should be aware that blocking the`accept()` operation completely will even prevent innocent clients from connection.  I prefer to accept connection anyway and close the bad one as soon as possible.